# Efficient way to find 200,000 product names in 20 million articles?

Tags: mysql, indexing, elasticsearch, faceted-search, named-entity-recognition

We have two (MySQL) databases, one with about 200.000 products (like "Samsung Galaxy S4", db-size 200 MB) and one with about 10 million articles (plain text, db-size 20GB) which can contain zero, one or many of the product names from the product database. Now we want to find product names in the article texts and store them as facets of the articles while indexing them in elasticsearch. Using regular expressions to find the products is pretty slow, we looked at Apache OpenNLP and Stanford Named Entity Recognizer, for both we have to train our own models and there are some projects at github for integrating those NER tools into elasticsearch, but they don't seem to be ready for production use.

Products and articles are added every day, so we have to run a complete recognition every day. Is NER the way to go? Or any other ideas? We don't have to understand the grammer etc. of the text, we only have to find the product name strings as fast as possible. We can't do the calculation in realtime because that's way to slow, so we have to pre-calculate the connection between articles and products and store them as facets, so we can query them pretty fast in our application.

**So what's your recommendation to find so many product names in so many articles?**

Comment: you can try to use a boolean full-text search which for sure it will be faster : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Comment: faster for what kind of task? While indexing in elasticsearch, we need to find all matching products for every article. So if we build a complete index, we have to search for all 200,000 product names in all 20 million articles. Using "MATCH AGAINST" queries for product names in articles could be an option, but wouldn't using elasticsearch be better here? What about something which is completly run in RAM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the issues you'll run into the most is consistency... new articles and new product names are always coming in and you'll have an "eventual consistency" problem. So there are three approaches that come to mind that I have used to tackle this kind of problem.

1. As suggested, use a full text search in MySQL, basically create a loop over your products table, and for each product name do a MATCH AGAIST query and insert productkey, and article key into a tie table. THis is fast, I used to run a system in SQL Server with over 90000 items being searched against 1B sentences. If you had a multithreaded java program that chunked up the categories and exectured the full text query, you may be surpised how fast this will be. Also, this can hammer your DB server.
2. Use Regex. Put all the products in a collection in memory, and regex find with that list against every document. This CAN be fast if you have your docs in something like hadoop, where it can be parallelized. You could run the job at night, and have it populate a MySQL table... This approach means you will have to start storing your docs in HDFS or some NOSQL solution, or import from MySQL to hadoop daily etc etc.
3. You can try doing it "at index time", so when a record is indexed in ElasticSearch the extraction will happen then and your facets will be built. I have only used SOLR for stuff like this... problem here is that when you add new products you will have to process in batch again anyway because the previously index docs will not have had the new products extracted from them.

so there may be better options, but the one that scales infinitely (if you can afford the machines) is option 2... the hadoop job.... but this means big change.

These are just my thoughts, so I hope others come up with more clever ideas

EDIT:
As for using NER, I have used NER extensively, mainly OpenNLP, and the problem with this is that what it extracts will not be normalized, or to put it another way, it may extract pieces and parts of a product name, and you will be left dealing with things like fuzzy string matching to align the NER Results to the table of products. OpenNLP 1.6 trunk has a component called the EntityLinker, which is designed for this type of thing (linking NER results to authoritative databases). Also, NER/NLP will not solve the consistency problem, because every time you change your NER model, you will have to reprocess.

Comment: I think we have to compare performance, a hadoop cluster is probably too much for only 20GB of data, but we are open for ideas. I think we will try to query mysql and elasticsearch itself. So you used multiple threads to query one large mysql fulltext index in parallel? Doesn't it make sense to load the index/data into ram / on ramdisk?

Comment: I agree that hadoop could be overkill, depending on your doc growth rate. The nice thing about the text index is you can do something like this  (pseudo):
for(product prod :products){
insert into doc_prod_tie(docid,prodid) select @prodid, docid from doc where match(doc.text) against (@productName in boolean mode)
}


you don't need to load docs into memory one at a time, you only need to look at each Product one at a time, and all hits on prods will be captured in one set operation with the full text query. Of course this is not the only way to get it done.

Comment: Works pretty well, the only problem we have is indexing speed of mysql: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22360657/speed-up-full-text-indexing-mysql

Comment: glad to hear it... one gotcha I had was that some of my search terms were 3 chars or less (acronyms), and at first I did not realize by default the MySQL full text engine ignores them. So I had to change this and reindex... and yes, initial indexing is a bit slow.

Comment: you wrote that you use a multithreaded java program for the match against queries. We tried to run multiple match against queries in parallel too, but it doesn't seem to scale very well. We had to switch to innodb for the results so that we don't suffer from table-level locking, but by increasing the number of match against queries running in parallel, we increased cpu utilization of the mysqld, but not the overall processing speed. Any ideas where to look after?

Comment: Well, The approach that worked for us was to keep track of where the processor left off by storing the last id processed, and only process  the delta of the last time the job ran. Then you only have to do the really expensive job against everything once, and then when brand new categories are involved, and even then, you only have to process the NEW category against everything. In simple terms, keep track of what you've processed, and only process new categories against everything, and don't process old categories against everything every time.
HTH

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest a preprocessing step : tokenization. If you do so for the product list and for the incoming articles, than you won't need to have a per-product search : the product list would be an automata where each transition is a given token.

That gives us a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) that you'll use to match products against texts, searching will look like :

```
products = []
availableNodes = dictionary.root
foreach token in text:
    foreach node in availableNodes:
        if node.productName:
            products.append(node.productName)
    nextAvailableNodes = [dictionary.root]
    foreach node in availableNodes:
        childNode = node.getChildren(token)
        if childNode:
            nextAvailableNodes.append(childNode)
    availableNodes = nextAvailableNodes
```

As far as I can tell, this algorithm is quite efficient and it allows you to fine-tune node.getChildren() function (e.g. to address capitalization or diacritics issues). Loading products lists as a a trie may take some time , in that case you could cache it as a binary file.

This simple method can easily be distributed using Hadoop or other MapReduce approach, either over texts or over product list, see for instance [this article](http://www.dcs.kcl.ac.uk/staff/csi/publications/HIM01DistrPatMatchAutomata.ps) (but you'll probably need more recent / accurate ones).